# How to count number of bytes in an integer

Tags: go

I have the following variables:

```
var foo int8
var bar [5]int8
```

I want to count number of bytes in both variables and output the sum - so right here it should be `1 + 5 = 6`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unsafe.Sizeof](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) (https://play.golang.org/p/FroasKud7I):

```
unsafe.Sizeof(foo) + unsafe.Sizeof(bar)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reflect.Size`, this returns a `uintptr` for some reason, but is actually just the exact same thing as `unsafe.SizeOf` without having to use `unsafe`.

```
var x [8]byte

t := reflect.TypeOf(x)

fmt.Println(t.Size())
```

The snags are going to be maps, slices, strings, and pointers, which you'll get the size of the header/metadata (or just the pointer size for pointers). If that's okay, great! If not, you can handle this in various ways, this is the best I have off the top of my head:

```
func UnderlyingSize(x interface{}) uintptr {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    t := v.Type()

    var size uintptr;

    switch t.Kind() {
    // For the builtin collections, we just multiply the len by the
    // element size, for maps also do the key
    case reflect.Map:
         l := uintptr(v.Len())
        size = t.Key().Size()*l + t.Elem().Size()*l
    case reflect.Slice:
        t := t.Elem();
        size = t.Size() * uintptr(v.Len())
    case reflect.Ptr:
        t := t.Elem();
        size = t.Size()
    // Strings are just byte arrays, so it's just the len
    case reflect.String:
        size = uintptr(v.Len())
    // For an interface, we need to find the underlying type
    case reflect.Interface:
        v := v.Elem()
        size = UnderlyingSize(v)
    // For anything else, including arrays, Size returns the correct value
    default:
        size = t.Size();
    }

    return size
}
```

There is an argument to be made for using `Cap` rather than `Len`, but it's easy enough to change yourself. You can also add `t.Size()` to any of these values if you want the size of the header information AND the underlying size. Note a word of warning that the real `map` probably takes more memory than just the key+value+header size, since there's probably some extra information under the hood.

If you have a data structure that's a collection, you'll have to implement something like this yourself, but if it's a simple struct (i.e. only made of POD structs and builtin types), you can simply add up `UnderlyingSize` of all the members.